# Exponential sums and random walks

Tags: probability

I was reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sum

In this article under “estimates” they say that the exponential sum is $O(\sqrt N)$ and thus resembles a random walk. Is there any reason to think of this sum as a random walk other than just a $\sqrt N$?

Comment: I suspect it is more the other way round.  A random walk of $N$ steps of length $1$ in random directions on a plane has this $O(\sqrt{N})$ property so it might be possible to say in some sense that "most" exponential sums do not have terms with special relationships and so can be treated like 2D random walks

Comment: @henry I didn’t quite follow what you said. Can you explain more? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the wikipedia section means this:

To the extent that the $x_n$ sequence can be considered random, each of $y_n = e(x_n) = \exp(2\pi i x_n)$ is a unit vector with a random direction, so the successive sums $y_1, y_1+y_2, y_1+y_2+y_3, \dots$ is a random walk on the $2$-D plane where each step is size $1$ with random direction.